# Using Hlookup with a Choose() Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use a Hlookup with the "Choose()" function as array. It works perfectly with a vlookup as showed below:

```
=VLOOKUP(1;CHOOSE({1,2};A1:A3;C1:C3);2;FALSE)
```

[image]

Why does it not work for a Hlookup as below:

```
=HLOOKUP(1;CHOOSE({1,2};A1:C1;A3:C3);2;FALSE)
```

[image]

Note: I am trying to fix my excel formula, so no VBA needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your Array is Horizontal.  You need to change your separators.

You can treat the Array `{1,2}` as the following range:

> |`1`|`2`|

This means that `CHOOSE({1,2},A1:A3,C1:C3)` can be treated as:

> |`=A1:A3`|`=C1:C3`|
>   or
>   |`=A1`|`=C1`|
>   |`=A2`|`=C2`|
>   |`=A3`|`=C3`|

You do a `VLOOKUP` on that, find `=A3`, and look in the second column: `=C3`.

Now, this also means that `CHOOSE({1,2},A1:C1,A3:C3)` can be represented like *this*:

> |`=A1:C1`|`=A3:C3`|
>   or
>   |`=A1`|`=B1`|`=C1`|`=A3`|`=B3`|`=C3`|

Do a `HLOOKUP` on that, find `=C1`, and...  Well, there *isn't* a second row.

This means we need a way to represent **this** instead:

> |`=A1:C1`|
>   |`=A3:C3`|
>   or
>   |`=A1`|`=B1`|`=C1`|
>   |`=A3`|`=B3`|`=C3`|

because then you find `=C1`, look in the second **row**, and get `=C3`.

Well, how do we do this?  Simple!  We just change `{1,2}` to `{1;2}`, because that represents

> |`1`|
>   |`2`|

instead:

```
=HLOOKUP(1;CHOOSE({1;2};A1:C1;A3:C3);2;FALSE)
```

(Incidentally, this means that `{1,2;3,4}` becomes the following:)

> |`1`|`2`|
>   |`3`|`4`|